# General Approach to Solving Cryptarithms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cryptarithm

I have recently started honing my problem-solving skills, starting with number-related problems. Cryptarithms have appeared frequently, so I was wondering whether there is some sort of general approach to solving these problems? Such as a sequence of reproducible steps?

I understand that for easier examples, such as "AB + AB + AB = CB" , common sense can be used to recognise simple facts (in this case, B must be 0 or 5). However, for harder examples that involve multiple solutions or higher-digit numbers, I find myself struggling without making any progress.

Guidance on how to approach these problems would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that there's unlikely to be a _general_ general algorithm; [generalized cryptarithms are NP-Complete](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/24658.24662).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I don't understand an NP-complete problem is in NP and hence can be solved by some algorithm. When you say "*general* general", perhaps you mean practically useful?

Comment: @RobArthan That is what I meant; I should probably have said something like 'unlikely to have any known algorithm much better than educated-guess-and-check'.

Comment: You might consider asking this at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ as there are probably people there with good strategies for these kinds of things.